# 3 dimensional Exterior Derivative

Tags: exterior-derivative

I have $dx=x^{1/2}\omega_1$, (so $\omega_1=x^{-1/2}dx$), and $\star dx=x^{1/2}\omega_2 \wedge \omega_3$ (where $\star$ is the Star Hodge Operator).

Then I have $d(x^{1/2}\omega_2 \wedge \omega_3)= -p \omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 \wedge \omega_3$, where $p$ is a constant.

What will $\omega_2 \wedge \omega_3$ be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the calculation,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{d}\bigl(x^{p+1/2}\,\omega_2\wedge\omega_3\bigr)
&= \mathrm{d}\bigl(x^p\,\,x^{1/2}\,\omega_2\wedge\omega_3\bigr)
= p x^{p-1}\mathrm{d}x\wedge x^{1/2}\,\omega_2\wedge\omega_3+ x^p\wedge\mathrm{d}\bigl(x^{1/2}\,\omega_2\wedge\omega_3\bigr)\\
&= p x^{p-1}\,x^{1/2}\omega_1\wedge x^{1/2}\,\omega_2\wedge\omega_3
   + x^p\wedge\bigl(-p\omega_1\wedge\omega_2\wedge\omega_3\bigr)\\
&= (p-p) \,x^{p}\omega_1\wedge\omega_2\wedge\omega_3 = 0,
\end{aligned}
$$
one sees that $x^{p+1/2}\,\omega_2\wedge\omega_3$ is a closed $2$-form.  Thus, there always exist (localy) functions $y$ and $z$ such that 
$$
x^{p+1/2}\,\omega_2\wedge\omega_3 = \mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}z,
$$
which is about all that one can say. Namely
$$
\omega_2\wedge\omega_3 = x^{-(p+1/2)}\,\mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}z
$$
locally for some functions $y$ and $z$, where $\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}z\not=0$.